# Physical significance of momentum eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

In an introductory textbook of Quantum Mechanics, I found the momentum eigenfunction in position space to be given as **Ne^ipx/h**.

Where N is the normalization factor and i is root of -1.

I don't understand clearly what this function signifies.
Does it tell us that the ampitude of finding a particle with momentum **p**
oscialltes as we move about the ***positon*** / ***x*** axis?

So is it that a particle is favoured to have certain momentum values in some special positions?

Comment: 1. If you are in position space, why does your function not depend on $x$? 2. We can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) here. 3. Why would you think it signifies anything other than any other wavefunction? 4. Try to compute $N$, and be prepared to be confused.

Comment: Sorry, for the typo, it does have the position term.

Comment: The probability to find the particle in a position depends on the MAGNITUDE of the wave function, which in this case is constant. ACuriosMind is correct, though, the proper normalization in this case is not a constant but the Dirac delta function, at least that's the lie we teach to our children, otherwise we would have to walk them trough a proper treatment of continuous linear operator spectra, which is a whole series of lectures for mathematicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particle with such a wave function is in a momentum eigenstate i.e. all measurements of momentum for the particle will always return the value **p**. The physically relevant quantity with respect to position is the amplitude modulus squared which by the Born interpretation gives us the probability of finding the particle at a given point. In this case, this probability turns out to be constant, which basically means a particle with precise momentum value can be absolutely anywhere with regard to position. This is in accordance with the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. Since uncertainty in p is 0, uncertainty in x is infinite, thus the particle can be found absolutely anywhere in space.